# Make feature class from table data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, table, feature-class

I would like to create a feature class using an attribute table of another feature class. However, it does not use XY coordinates, so I can't create it that way. I thought I could export the data and make it a feature class but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you post a short example of the data. If there is no way to locate the data (i.e. geocode, xy event) then there is no way to create a gis feature class.  Please post any more information to your original question by hitting the edit. And read the Help FAQ for more information.

Comment: In addition to Brad's comments, could you please explain why you want to do this?  This could be helpful in finding a new approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new blank feature class in your .gdb, when you get to the field names page, click import and choose your original feature class. Then right click your newly created feature class, and choose load data and add your attribute table, map the field names to the existing field names and viola.